# Error en método de clase con librería pyVat.api

Tags: python

El siguiente método me devuelve el error: <pyVat.api.Validator object at 0x0000018F4009B7C0>

```
def check_vat(self):
    self.entry_check.delete(0, "end")

    country = self.entry_country.get()
    vat = self.entry_vat.get()
        
    validator = Validator(country+vat)

    if validator.validate() is True:
        self.entry_check.insert(0, "El número VAT ES válido")

    else:
        self.entry_check.insert(0, "El número VAT NO ES válido")
```

Sin embargo si lo ejecuto así, no falla. No entiendo donde está el problema.

```
from pyVat.api import Validator

country = input("Pais: ")
vat = input("VAT: ")
validator = Validator(country+vat)

print(country)
print(vat)

if validator.validate() is True:
    print("El número VAT ES válido")

else:
    print("El número VAT NO ES válido")
```

Esta es la salida:

```
PS C:\code\scripts\validador_vat> & C:/Python310/python.exe c:/code/scripts/validador_vat/check_vat.py
es
b70110010
```

Comment: Sería de gran utilidad que pusieras un print() de los `vat` y `country` para ver que le estás pasando al constructor (en ambos casos).

Comment: Muestra la salida para ambos casos ...